# How to serve a Flutter web app using Django?

Tags: python, django, flutter, flutter-web

After building a flutter web app with

```
flutter build web
```

I want to deploy this with dango server, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your backend is an API Rest and does not render the HTML.

The "right" way will be to have a service for the SPA, and another for the API. For example, with docker, droplets, kubernetes, DO and Heroku.

Another way that I'm thinking is... you specified a route (like example.com/) to serve the flutter web project (I mean the HTML), and the other routes can be the endpoints.

Comment: The last way is what I want, after i enter like example.com/, i want flutter web to work, other routes is post api using djangorestframework.

Comment: In that case, you have to insert the index.html on that route and serve all the required files